# Hadoop "not getting namenode with jps command" why namenode is not starting

Tags: hadoop

```
hadoop1@xyzfsdemo:/usr/local/hadoop$ sbin/start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop1-namenode-xyzfsdemo.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop1-datanode-xyzfsdemo.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop1-secondarynamenode-xyzfsdemo.out
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop1-resourcemanager-xyzfsdemo.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop1-nodemanager-xyzfsdemo.out
hadoop1@xyzfsdemo:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
52396 DataNode
53151 Jps
53072 NodeManager
52660 SecondaryNameNode
52860 ResourceManager
```

Comment: Detail out your ptoblem

Comment: Check the namenode logs and find the exact issue. I believe you are starting this for the first time. One question, did you formatted the namenode before trying to start it.

Comment: do i have to formate namenode every time before start it .

Comment: Thank for your response, yeah i am very new to hadoop, i am from oracle DBA background ...

Answer (score 0):

you should format your namenode every time before starting that.

```
$HADOOP_INSTALL/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Comment: can you please tell me why we need to format nodename each time before starting hadoop ??

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: this is a rule in hadoop. I dont know what concept is behind that.